# Using custom directive with isolated scope, in a modal

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, modal-dialog, angularjs-scope

I use a custom directive to get places from Google API. This directive works like a charm in a controller. But when I want to use it inside a modal, it doesn't work any more. It's a question of scope, but I can't figure out what's exactly happened. Any idea ?

My directive :

```
 'use strict';
angular.module('app').directive('googleplace', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
      ngModel: '=',
      details: '=?'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, model) {
      var options;
      options = {
        types: ['address'],
        componentRestrictions: {}
      };
      scope.gPlace = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element[0], options);
      google.maps.event.addListener(scope.gPlace, 'place_changed', function() {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          scope.details = scope.gPlace.getPlace();
          if (scope.details.name) {
            element.val(scope.details.name);
            model.$setViewValue(scope.details.name);
            element.bind('blur', function(value) {
              if (value.currentTarget.value !== '') {
                element.val(scope.details.name);
              }
            });
          }
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

My modal controller :

```
    modalInstance = $modal.open
        templateUrl: "modal.html"
        controller: ($scope, $modalInstance) ->
            $scope.$watch 'placeDetails', ->
              _.forEach $scope.placeDetails.address_components, (val, key) ->
                $scope.myaddress = val.short_name + ' '  if val.types[0] is 'street_number'
                return
```

And finally, my html :

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Start typing" ng-model="address" details="placeDetails" googleplace />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" ng-model="myaddress">
    </div>
</div>
```

I should have the ng-model="address" populated with the result of the call to Google Place API, and the ng-model="myaddress" populated by the $watch, but nothing happens.

Here is my plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/iEAooKgfUUfxoBWm8mgw?p=preview

Click on "Open modal" causes the error : Cannot read property 'address_components' of undefined

Comment: can you please create small [plunkr](http://plnkr.co)

Comment: I have updated my post with the plunkr

Comment: Is there anybody who could help me?

Comment: In model.html you have used two inputs with different ng-model like address and myaddress...looks like you want to assigin whatever inside address to myaddress .If So than you can call a function on address blur and assign whatever address to myaddress like --- function onaddresschange(){ $scope.myaddress = address }; and remove watch from controller

Answer (score 0):

[working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/RImlCbCMlHOhd9eucTYU?p=preview)

[According to how to create modal in angularjs](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

```
Extra things that i added : 

1 : New Controller for modal

2 : Blur function that fires on property change Instead of $watch
```